# Why getExtra() from Bundle is null when but bundle mMap has got this value?

Tags: android, android-studio, bundle, parcelable

As above in question, why?

[code screenshot which describes this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoNwx.png)

Send data to other activity:

```
private void replaceActivity(LoginModel loginModel) {
    Context context = activity.getApplicationContext();
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.putExtra("accessKey", loginModel.getAccessKey());
    intent.putExtra("loginData", loginModel.getUserData());
    context.startActivity(intent);
    activity.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
}
```

Comment: use intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("loginData",loginModel.getUserData());

Comment: What is UserData? A custom object? An array?

Comment: Are you correctly implementing parcelable on the userdata object? Post the object code plz

Comment: your 
 intent.putExtra("accessKey", loginModel.getAccessKey());
and you getting
String value = bundle.getString("ACCESS_KEY",null);
replace this by
String value = bundle.getString("accessKey","");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1: Pass Data in intent**

```
private void replaceActivity(LoginModel loginModel) {
    Context context = activity.getApplicationContext();
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.putExtra("accessKey", loginModel.getAccessKey());
    intent.putExtra("loginData", loginModel.getUserData());
    context.startActivity(intent);
    activity.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
}
```

**Step 2: Get Data in MainActivity**

```
String accessKey = getIntent().getStringExtra("accessKey");
UserData userData = getIntent.getParcelableArrayExtra("loginData");
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are putting

```
intent.putExtra("accessKey", loginModel.getAccessKey());
```

then get it by`bundle.getString("accessKey");`

Answer (score 0):

When you pass intent.putExtra();
then you get data .getString();
and also if you want to check null then check by below code :

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null && bundle.getString("accessKey") != null) {
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If UserData is a custom object, you can use Gson to convert an object to a JSONObject and pass it on bundle.

In First Activity

```
Intent activity = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra("accessKey", loginModel.getAccessKey());
activity.putExtra("loginData",
                  new Gson().toJson(loginModel.getUserData()));
startActivity(activity);
```

In Second Activity

```
String jsonLoginData;
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
   jsonLoginData = extras.getString("loginData");
}
UserData loginData = new Gson().fromJson(jsonLoginData, UserData.class);
```